# Getting Error in WPF contol Library

Tags: wpf

I am creating WPF control library and trying to create dynamic columns in `DataGrid` but getting error mentione below.

> The type or namespace name 'DataGridTextColumn' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please suggest me where I am going wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace TestWPFLibrary
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Create a new column to add to the DataGrid
            var textcol = new DataGridTextColumn();
            //Create a Binding object to define the path to the DataGrid.ItemsSource property
            //The column inherits its DataContext from the DataGrid, so you don't set the source
            Binding b = new Binding("LastName");
            //Set the properties on the new column
            textcol.Binding = b;
            textcol.Header = "Last Name";
            //Add the column to the DataGrid
           dataGrid1.Columns.Add(textcol);

        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestWPFLibrary.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
            xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
             xmlns:my1="clr-namespace:TestWPFLibrary">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <my:DataGrid Height="288" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,12,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=b}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: try to put your code in `Loaded` Event

Comment: Hey exactly what i have to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the `WpfTookit` `DataGrid` in wich the `dataGrid1.Columns.Add(textcol);`
is expecting a `Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn`.
you can either change the `WpfTookit` to the built in `DataGrid`, or change the `DataGridTextColumn`:

```
var textcol = new Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn();
```

Comment: there was no datagrid in my toolbox so i added by right clicking and choosing components.So is this a problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<my:DataGrid x:Name="ConfigGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <my:DataGrid.Columns>
  <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Entry_Number}" Header="Id" Visibility="Hidden" />
  <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Part_CatalogNumber}" Header="Part Number" />
  <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Sensor_Type}" Header="Sensor Type Id" />
  <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Date_Entered}" Header="Date Created" />
  <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=User_Comments}" Header="User Comments" Width="250" />
  <my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <Button Name="btnOldDelete" Click="btnOldDelete_Click">Delete</Button>
         </DataTemplate>
      </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </my:DataGrid.Columns>
  </my:DataGrid>
```